# Execute one command after completing another command in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I read the information of my provinces from Api and then I want to get the information of cities from Api, but when I want to apply for the city, the property state is still empty and this operation is not done, how can I solve my problem?

```
        export class StateComponent implements OnInit {
          constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private _service: AssessmentServiceService) { }
         ngOnInit(): void {
        this.flagProgressBar = true;
        this._service.getDataStates().subscribe(
          (res: IState[]) => {
           this.state = res;
            
          }
        )
        for (const index in this.state) {
          this._service.getDataCitys(this.state[index].stateId).subscribe(
            (res: ICity[]) => {
              for (const indexC in res) {
                this.city.push(res[indexC]);
              }
            }
          )
        }
      }
      flagProgressBar: boolean = false;
      state: IState[] = [];
      city: ICity[] = [];
   }
```

Question 2: Which method starts working after ngOnInit is finished? I want to change the flagProgressBar after all operations are completed.

Answer (score 0):

add the second subscribe into the first subscribe. so it wont run till first comes back

```
this._service.getDataStates().subscribe(
      (res: IState[]) => {
       this.state = res;
       for (const index in this.state) {
           this._service.getDataCitys(this.state[index].stateId).subscribe(...)
       }    
    }
```

for your second question either you can put the flag into the second subscribe. or you can use another method that runs after OnInit, (for example ngAfterViewInit())

Comment: Is it possible to do this using async await? Instead, place two commands inside each other.

Comment: The ngAfterViewInit command is not read after getting the city information, I want it to be executed after reading the cities.

Comment: i never used async await in angular. regarding the cities, you have no idea when that will complete, so the best choice is to put it into the second subscibe

Comment: When using ngAfterViewChecked, I get the following warning: `ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
    at throwErrorIfNoChangesMode (core.js:8092)`

Comment: I want to set the proprty flagProgressBar to false when all operations inside ngOnInit are done. How do I do this?

Comment: add the flag to the second subscribe (the nested subscribe)